# APEX - how to call store procedure base on values of items on the page

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

similiar problem has already been mentioned, described and solved here using dynamic actions but I still can't implement it in my case.

I have a form (created authomatically but page creator) to change password in remote database. There are three items

- login : P15_UNAME (select list)  LOV
- new password: P15_NEW (password)
- button to execute: SUBMIT (button).

Button fires a simple stored procedure:

```
declare
  success int;
  msg varchar(100);
begin
  SYS.CHANGEPASSWORD@abc(
    PUSERNAME => :P15_UNAME,
    PNEWPASSWORD => :P15_NEW,
    PRESULT => success,
    PMESSAGE => msg);
 if success = 0 then
     apex_application.g_print_success_message := msg;
 else
     apex_application.g_print_success_message := '<span style="color:red">'  || msg || '</span>';
 end if ;
end ;
```

Unfortunately choosen/typed values of login and password are not called by stored procedure.  I probably should use dynamic action but have no idea how to call store procedure and dynamic simultaneously.  Could you give me some hints please.

K.

Comment: If your username is in item P15_COMBOVALUE then you should use that in the procedure call, not P15_UNAME which will just return null if there is no such item. No dynamic action is required.

Comment: you are right - it is of course my mistake. item with login calles P15_UNAME .

Comment: IS P15_UNAME displaying username and returning an id? (What is the value in session when you submit?)

Comment: P15_UNAME display and return the same value - username.   And for this item I set "default value"  so it always return that value.

Comment: So what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @Tony the point is how to call my procedure with parameters I set on the form. Doesn't  metter what login I choose  procedure always get default value from select list.  Doesn't metter what password I type second procedure parameter always gets empty value.

Comment: Can you replicate the problem on apex.oracle.com?  You could create a stored procedure there called `CHANGEPASSWORD` and call that.  In that procedure use apex_debug calls you write out parameter values.

Comment: debugging is unexplored feature by me yet but let me a while I will try to read values of my items from debugger.

Comment: @Tony & others 
thanks for your help. All code I wrote in my question is correct - it works. I did a small mistake in appliacation code and my procedure took wrong parameters - my fault :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to pass the page item values directly into the database?  Your procedure / procedure call should look something like this.

```
-- database
PROCEDURE p_change_details(p_uname varchar2, p_password varchar2) 
IS 
  success int;
  msg varchar(100);
begin
  SYS.CHANGEPASSWORD@abc(
    PUSERNAME => p_uname,
    PNEWPASSWORD => p_password,
    PRESULT => success,
    PMESSAGE => msg);
 if success = 0 then
     apex_application.g_print_success_message := msg;
 else
     apex_application.g_print_success_message := '<span style="color:red">'  || msg || '</span>';
 end if ;
end ;

--APEX
p_change_details(:P15_UNAME, :P15_NEW)
```

Comment: Well it is probably a proper way - to pass parameters rather to local procedure than directly into (remote) database. Anyway the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Dynamic Action to execute a PL/SQL code on button click.

refer this example- [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312328/how-can-i-create-oracle-apex-server-side-live-validation-without-need-to-submit)

Hope this will help you. Let me know for any question.